# Is there a way to factor the finite sum of products $a_0x_0+a_1x_1+a_0a_1x_0x_1+\cdots$ to a product of $(a_n+b_nx_n)$

Tags: complex-geometry, products

I know how to factor out $\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_nx_n+b_n)$ , but is there a way to reverse the process to get that product from $$a_0x_0+a_1x_1+a_0a_1x_0x_1+\cdots+\prod_{m=0}^{n}a_mx_m$$

I have 9 sets of $(ax+b)$ and need to be able to use decimals and functions eg.
$\sinh(a_0a_1)x_0x_1+\cos(b_0b_2)x_0x_2...$ where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are real, and $x_n$ is a non-real constant including, but not limited to $i^2=-1$, $j^2=1$, $\lambda^{1/2}=-1$, and $\epsilon^2=0$
For the solution, I am fine with assuming symmetry of the product (or assuming all $a_n,x_n\in\Bbb{R}$). I will be able to find exceptions and changes in rules. (eg. not allowing $(-1)^2$ to be assumed as 1)

Comment: The product does not depend on the order of the $a_i,b_i,x_i$ but the sum depends on the order of the $a_i,x_i.$

Comment: Also, if you are going to start with $a_0x_0,$ you probably want to start your product with $i=0,$ Also, $\prod_{m=0}^{n} a_nx_n=(a_nx_n)^m.$ You probably want $\prod_m a_mx_m.$ But it is still not possible.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I use n as the sum variable because I use the imaginary i and j units so commonly that $a_i$ could mean $a_0$ or a for the imaginary axis

Comment: That wasn't my point, but there is a error in my point. $$\prod_{m=0}^{n} c_n=c_n^{n+1}.$$ You want $\ prod_{m=0}^{n} c_m=c_0c_1\cdots c_n.$ So where you wrote $a_nx_n$ in the product, you want $a_mx_m.$

Comment: In any event, there is no way to write it this way due to symmetry of the product and lack of symmetry in the result you want.

Comment: I just noticed that mistake! Thank you very much!